# Context menu should appear only on TreeView child nodes

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, wpf-controls, contextmenu

I have a TreeView with a ContextMenu on the TreeViewItems. When I right click on the TreeViewItems, contextMenu appears quite nicely. But I dont want the ContextMenu to appear on the Parent items. It should only appear on the child nodes. I have only one hirarchy in the TreeView i.e. N parents will have M children all on the same level. This is my XAML for TreeView and ContextMenu

```
   <TreeView Margin="2,0,0,0"  ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData}" Width="390">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle >
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                  <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding DataContext.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                      <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ContextMenu Name="contextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
                                        <MenuItem Name="menuItem" Header="Rename" Command="{Binding RenameCommand}" />
                                    </ContextMenu>
                     </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                         </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle >
```

Comment: Not your problem but is `Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"` instead of `Value="{Binding DataContext.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` really not working? It should be the same.

Comment: @WQad, is it the same TV as from yesterday?

Comment: @GarryVass no that does not work because ContextMenu is not in the visuals of treeview. so ihave to specify Relative source like that

Comment: @WQad, I think your last comment was for LPL, no?  But did you get the attached behaviour working?

Comment: yeah it was meant to go to @LPL :)
No I still did not get it working bro. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @WQad, yes.  Did you see the update about the RelayCommand class?  You need to use a strongly typed RelayCommand